# WordPress 4.4 shortcode texturize issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Sadly, my plugin stop working now when users update from WordPress 3 to 4.4, the plugin help to embed JWplayer HTML5 player on posts with shortcodes, so with new update the shortcodes not output the video player, just the shortcode code

```
[jwplayer7sc&nbsp;file=”https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c74KCFIaRIw”&nbsp;title=”efzef”&nbsp;description=”zef”&nbsp;image=”zefzef”]
```

You can see the problem [here](http://jwplayer7.com/)

This is my code:

```
function jw7sc_video_shortcode($atts) {

// extract all video shortcode parameters and pass them to @VARS

 extract( shortcode_atts( array(

  'id' => generateRandomString(),
  'file' => '',
  'title' => '',
  'description' => '',
  'image' => '',
  'width' => '',
  'height' => '',
  'autostart' => '',
  'mute' => '',
  'controls' => '',
  'repeat' => '' ,
  'displaytitle' => '',
  'displaydescription' => '',
  'androidhls' => '',
  'stretching' => '',
  'skin' => ''

   ), $atts ) );

 // check if options not yet configured
  if(!is_bool(jw7sc_options())){

 extract(jw7sc_options());

 }

 else {
  // if options not configured yet show message
  return('to show the video player Please Edit Jwplater 7 Settings First from admin menu ( Settings > Jwplayer 7 shortcode ) ');

 }


 return jw7sc_player(
           $shortcode_width = $width, // custom shortcode width return (integer)
           $shortcode_height = $height, // custom shortcode height (integer)
           $shortcode_autostart = $autostart, // custom shortcode ausotart mode return (bool)
           $shortcode_mute = $mute, // custom shortcode mute mode return (bool)
           $shortcode_controls = $controls, // custom shortcode controls mode return (bool) 
           $shortcode_repeat = $repeat, //custom shortcode repeat mode return (bool)
           $shortcode_displaytitle = $displaytitle,
           $shortcode_displaydescription = $displaydescription,
           $shortcode_androidhls = $androidhls,
           $shortcode_stretching = $stretching,
           $shortcode_skin = $skin,
           $jw7sc_media_type = 'file', 
           $jw7sc_playlist = false, // check if media contains playlist ids
           $jw7vid_player_size = $jw7sc_player_size,
           $jw7video_title = $title, // media title
           $jw7video_description = $description, // media description
           $jw7vid_width = $jw7sc_fixed_width, //fixed player width
           $jw7vid_height = $jw7sc_fixed_height, //fixed player height
           $jw_player_id = $id, // custom random player id return (rand() number)
           $jw7_playable_source = $file, // get playable media source
           $jw7sc_license_key, // options license key retun (string)
           $jw7sc_player_logo, // get player logo return (string)
           $jw7_video_image = $image, // get video image return (string)
           $usecustomskinActive = $jw7sc_use_custom_skin, // if custom skin check box checked
           $jw7sc_select_skin, // selected skin
           $jw7sc_active_color_skin, // get custom active skin color
           $jw7sc_inactive_color_skin, // get custom inactive skin color
           $jw7sc_bg_color_skin, // get custom background skin color
           $jw7sc_stretching_mode, // get stretching mode
           $jw7sc_aboutlink_mode, // aboutlink mode
           $jw7sc_abouttext_mode, // abouttext mode
           $jw7sc_displaytitle_mode, // displaytitle mode return (bool)
           $jw7sc_displaydescription_mode, //displaydescription mode return (bool)
           $jw7sc_playlist_mode, 
           $jw7sc_sharing_mode, // share mode 
           $jw7sc_share_heading, // share heading return (string)
           $jw7sc_android_mode, //androidhls mode return (bool)
           $jw7sc_repeat_mode, // repeat mode return (bool)
           $jw7sc_render_mode, // render mode
           $jw7sc_mute_mode, // mute mode return (bool)
           $jw7sc_autostart_mode, // autostart mode return (bool)
           $jw7sc_controls_mode, // show controls or hide return (bool)
           $jw7sc_preroll_client_ad, 
           $jw7sc_preroll_tag_ad, 
           $jw7sc_preroll_skipoffset_ad, //  skipoffset retun (integer) default value = 5 / (seconds)
           $jw7sc_preroll_skipmsg_ad, // skipmsg return (string)
           $jw7sc_preroll_skiptext_ad // skiptext return (string)
           );
          }
         // apply our jwplayer7sc shortcode


         add_shortcode('jwplayer7sc' , 'jw7sc_video_shortcode');

         add_filter( 'no_texturize_shortcodes', 'no_texturize_shortcodes_example' );

          function no_texturize_shortcodes_example( $shortcodes ) {
$shortcodes[] = 'jwplayer7sc';
return $shortcodes;
          }
```

jw7sc_player(shortcode params........) function return video player

Comment: any chance we can skip the plugin altogether and just instantiate jwplayer with some javascript and the jwplayer api? can you try another plugin?

Comment: also, if it's just a vimeo embed you need then there's no need to use a shortcode, just use vimeo's normal embed.

Comment: also for regular mp4 files, the media player built into wordpress is just a regular html5 player which will play pretty much anything jwplayer can.

Comment: @ElonZito thanks for reply , but the problem is Im the developer of the plugin , and Im obligated to use jwplayer ! , what u think ?

Comment: lol, then you definitely need to maintain it, haha! no i don't think you're obligated to use jwplayer but if your shortcode isn't working then it's the instantiation of the shortcode, not the player that i'm concerned about. i would check the syntax of your php and make sure there were no updates that might have effected how you're writing the plugin.